# Salesforce apex how to include soqlbuilder

Tags: invalid

I am new to salesforce apex and getting the error below. I have a request object and passings its id and the request object query and fetching filters. The fetched filters are then used to fetch records from listings object .

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: SoqlBuilder at line 7 column 26

**Controller**

```
public class searchcontroller {

    public List<Listing__c> getListings() {
       String qid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  
       List<Request__c> rq = [select baths__c,beds__c,max_price__c,min_price__c,Contact__c from request__c where id =: qid];
       String qr = '';
       String soql = new SoqlBuilder().selectx(new Set<Object>{'id','name'}).fromx('listing__c').wherex(new AndCondition());
       if(rq['baths__c']){
           soql.add(new FieldCondition().field('baths__c').equals(rq['baths__c']));
       }
       if(rq['beds__c']){
           soql.add(new FieldCondition().field('beds__c').equals(rq['beds__c']));
       }
       if(rq['min_price__c']){
          soql.add(new FieldCondition().field('min_price__c').greaterThan(rq['min_price__c']));
       }
       if(rq['max_price__c']){
          soql.add(new FieldCondition().field('max_price__c').greaterThan(rq['max_price__c']));
       }
       soql.toSoql(new soql.SoqlOptions().wildcardStringsInLikeOperators());
       System.debug(soql);

    } 

}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your requirement, can you share them briefly in bullet point by **Edit** your question?

Comment: I have edited my question. http://apex-commons.github.io/query/soql-builder/ This is where I am using soqlbuilder . I have searched all over how to use the elaborated class "soqlbuilder" but could not find any help. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't have the utility open source classes. You can download the source (if you are only interested in using specific classes) or the manage/unmanage package from below link and it should work:

https://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/